# How to change icon size in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

How can I change the icon size in Ubuntu 14.04, the icon size is larger than I would like and I want to change it to be smaller

[image: desktop screenshot]

I need to resize side icon ( Launcher icon )

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings > Appearance > and move the Launcher icon size as required.

[image]

Comment: @Rinzwind Then why say "I need to resize side icon ( Launcher icon )" if he means the desktop?

Comment: I had to look 3 more times before I saw the line underneath the pixs :X :X I am getting old. Have an upvote in return ;-)